# How would I make a circuit that is repeating that you can turn off and on?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

I've been trying to make a firework launcher that repeats but I can only have it so it can turn on but never off. I've been using repeaters to go in a circle. I'm on Xbox 360 edition.

Answer (score 0):

Feeding a signal from a repeater into another repeater from the side should toggle it off. You'll see a little bedrock line on the repeater. Turn the inputting repeater off to turn the loop on again.